# How do you ping / contact a user?

Tags: support, chat

Some users who have contributed good question and answers seam to have gone in active. What is the best way to get them back on the site?

Also some questions could do with attention of a perticular user as they have given good answers in the past. How can you get their attention.

Comment: You can leave a comment on their post or ping them in chat if you can find them around. You *could* email them *if* they have listed their email address publicly in their profile.

Comment: How do you invite someone one to chat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I appreciate your efforts to make this site grow and attract new (or in this case old) users, but I feel you may be a little too enthusiastic.

First of all, Buddhism SE is doing a great job for a beta site of this age. Personally I think the question quality could be a bit better, but if I look at number of users, visits and questions, this site is doing great.

Now, if a user has decided not to visit this site anymore, he/she may have perfectly good reasons for this. There is no possibility for users to send messages to others users outside of the StackExchange website unless they've provided you with their email themselves (e.g. in their profile). This is intentional(!) because the last thing we want to do is annoy people by sending them unwanted emails.

You can attract the attention of a user that is still visiting StackExchange sites by typing @username (replace 'username' with their actual username and skip the spaces if there are any) in a comment or chat message. If you do this a notification of your comment/chat message will appear in that user's StackExchange inbox in the top bar.